# which authentication method is better for dealing with Google api and Google accounts on android?

Tags: android, oauth, google-api, google-api-java-client, accountmanager

follow the link: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Authentication 
There are 4 methods there, which are:
1. OAuth 1.0a
2. OAuth 2.0 draft 10 (JavaDoc, specification)
3. Android AccountManager
4. ClientLogin (legacy method that only works with some Google APIs)

Since Googler doesn't talk too much about making the choice, I just wonder which one is better for android app dev?
also, what's pros and cons for that choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android AccountManager. Use nothing else.